# How can I make my user services wait till the network is online?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, systemd-networkd

I have written a couple of systemd user service files which I want users to enable and which need a working network connection. I thought that would be as easy as:

```
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
```

However, the services seem to start too early, and in `journalctl` I see:

```
network-online.target: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit network-online.target failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Then I searched more and tried

```
Wants=network.target
After=network.target
```

and did `sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`.

Now I have in `journalctl`:

```
network.target: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit network.target failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

And again the service starts too early.

Is that message supposed to be there? How can I debug my problem?

---

**EDIT**: the reason is simple and specifically stated in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User):

> `systemd --user` runs as a separate process from the `systemd --system` process. User units can not reference or depend on system units.

[This forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1448518#p1448518) seems to suggest a simple solution: I should `link` the necessary system unit as a user, thus creating a symlink to it available on the unit search path.

After doing that, I don't see any `No such file or directory` messages, however, I still can't make the services actually run after the network is online.
I have tried linking `network.target`, `network-online.target` and `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`, setting my units to depend on each of them, with no success. When I check the linked unit's status in user mode,  <strike>they are all</strike> some of them are dead, e.g.:

```
$ systemctl --user status network.target
● network.target - Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/network.target; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget
$ systemctl status network.target
● network.target - Network
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/network.target; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active since Sat 2015-07-18 19:20:11 MSK; 3h 35min ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget

Jul 18 19:20:11 calc-server systemd[1]: Reached target Network.
Jul 18 19:20:11 calc-server systemd[1]: Starting Network.
```

However, I can see `network-online.target` active in user mode after linking it:

```
$ systemctl --user status network-online.target
● network-online.target - Network is Online
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/network-online.target; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active since Sun 2015-07-19 00:35:38 MSK; 2min 48s ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget

Jul 19 00:35:38 calc-server systemd[469]: Reached target Network is Online.
Jul 19 00:35:38 calc-server systemd[469]: Starting Network is Online.
```

Comment: I hope you'll have an answer.

Comment: @Deleteme Thanks, I think I found the cause of this (see update), but not how to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this problem? Also, I notice you emphasise that only *some* linked units are dead. Which are the ones that worked, and how do they differ?

Comment: @Sparhawk unfortunately not. As a workaround, I just use timers set to several seconds after boot. The question has an example: network-online target is active after linking, and network target is not.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but I'm looking for something to fire *every time* the network resumes, to check my email after resuming from suspend. I thought this would be the way to do it. I see the examples now. I thought you meant some custom services fired and some did not. However, I see now you are talking about the user versions of the network targets.

Comment: @LevLevitsky what commands did you really use to `link` the units? I tried `systemctl --user link /lib/systemd/system/network.target` and then with `systemctl --user status network.target` still got `Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)`...

Comment: @TCB13 I think that's pretty much what I did, except on my system `network.target` is at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/network.target`.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Something seems to be wrong here, because with `cat` I get the file on the path, however systemd can't read it, look at this: http://pastebin.com/RpsbP3qg

Comment: @TCB13 You are running `systemctl --user` as root, I'm not sure how that should work. Running it as user works for me (creates a symlink).

Comment: @LevLevitsky that's a good point.

Comment: On arch: `systemctl --user link /usr/lib/systemd/system/network-online.target`

Answer (score 6):

As this topic is No1 in google search results I share an alternate solution for all who will face the same problem.

In my system I added a simplified equivalent to `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` (which is `WantedBy=network-online.target`) and stored it in user services directory:

```
[Unit]
Description=User Wait for Network to be Configured

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then I made my user services to depend on this new one:

```
Wants=networkd-wait-online.service
After=networkd-wait-online.service
```

However, `Wants=` does not seem to be required due to `WantedBy=default.target`. You can remove `WantedBy=default.target` so this makes `network-wait-online.service` optional, but you certainly need `Wants=network-wait-online.service` then.

Original service `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` contains more dependencies, but they do not seem to be working in user context. Someone may provide user running equivalents for all of these dependencies, e.g. by using `systemctl --user link` for `network.target` and `network-online.target` as in other suggestions here, but I decided to keep it simple ;)

Note that despite of making a symlink to system service you do **NOT** tell your `systemd --user` manager to use some events from `systemd --system` manager to watch on a system service state, but make it to run another instance of this service from user context.

Answer (score 3):

Since you cannot depend on a system service, your only solution is to provide a user service that detects whether the network is online.  (Or make your services system services.)  Details for a "detect-online" user service would depend on your definition of "online".  It could wait for a ping to 8.8.8.8 to succeed, for instance.  Or for a DNS name resolution to succeed.  For instance, in a similar situation with vpnc, I wait for a ping to a vpn IP to succeed.

Then you can make your user services depend on (After=) your detect-online user service.

```
#!/bin/sh

host="${1:-8.8.8.8}"

pingcheck() {
  ping -n -c 1 -w 5 $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# Do you want a timeout ?
while :; do
  pingcheck ${host} && exit 0
  sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems reasonable and simple enough. But if 10 users enable my user service, there will be 10 instances pinging the same server simultaneously, which seems a bit redundant. In practice this is probably not at issue, but I was asking this in the hope of getting a single "online flag" available to all user services. No better solutions have yet been suggested, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to test something like this:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/foo.service
[Unit]
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/logger -t foo "testing online target"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Followed by:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable foo.service
```

Comment: But this is a system service, and I am trying to set up a user service.